# Array Subtraction and Assigning array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays coming from the database using the 2 while loops .

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
    {
        $surveyscnt[$row2['user_grp_id']]=$row2['COUNT( * )'];
    }

    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3))
    {
        $ndhcnt[$row3['group_id']]=$row3['headcount'];
    }
```

Can anyone guide me on how to do the following inside the foreach loop

Please see the foreach loop below

```
    foreach($surveyscnt as $node => $headcount){
            if($ndhcnt[$node]!=$headcount){             
                $pIdsNself = getAllParentsNself(array(**NEED TO CALL group_id**));
                updateRollups($pIdsNself,**NEED TO PUT THE DIFFERENCE of(COUNT*-headcount)** );
            }
    }
```

Any sort of help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, let me know if any issue.

1. In your sql query put `COUNT( * ) AS cnt` and in while you fetch it like : `$surveyscnt[$row2['user_grp_id']]=$row2['cnt'];`
2. $pIdsNself = `getAllParentsNself(array(**NEED TO CALL group_id**));` Here $node is your group id(as per your coding) so change the line to `getAllParentsNself(array($node));`
3. `updateRollups($pIdsNself,**NEED TO PUT THE DIFFERENCE of(COUNT*-headcount)** );`, Here you have both count* and head count so thi line will be `updateRollups($pIdsNself,($headcount-$ndhcnt[$node]) );`

Comment: Thanks man :) But instead of $headcount I needed to put $surveyscnt[$node]